# Problem when deploying Shiny app. Cannot find "tidyverse"

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse, shinyapps

I'm new at shiny. I'm trying to deploy my first App. It worwed perfectly on my computer (using R studio). But when depploying there seems to be a strange problem with dependencies. Particularly, the deployed app shows the following error message

> An error has occurred The application failed to start: exited
> unexpectedly with code 1
>
> Error in value[3L] : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
> Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne ->
>  Ejecución interrumpida

I believe you can see it here: https://cvfh.shinyapps.io/shiny_debates_latamv3/

My code goes like this:

```
# packages
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(amap)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plotly)
library(bslib)
library(dendextend)

# data
base <- read.csv("data/xxxx.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
.....

# UI
ui <- navbarPage(
....

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output) { ...
```

I had and reinstalled tidyverse , the R version, R studio, and de problem persists. I also tried using specific packages instead of tidyverse (i.e ggplot2) and the message just changed the name but persisted alike.
Any clue or help? I couldn't be more thankful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#using-your-r-packages-in-the-cloud

Comment: Do you have `library(tidyverse)` in your code?

Comment: yes, sorry! it is my first question here too. at the beggining of the script I have the libarys. then, data, which is referred in a relative folder. and then the ui and server function. (it is an app.R file)

Comment: I would add the `library(...)` statements in a file called `global.R` which is in the same directory as the files `ui.R` and `server.R`. This will load the libraries in both server and UI functions.